# How to access and edit GRUB files on SSD from Live CD?

Tags: debian, partition, grub2, grub, debian-installer

Is it possible to access and edit GRUB files on SSD from Live CD? I need edit `/etc/grub.d/10_linux` **/boot** is in separate partition on SSD. If that's possible, how to do this using Knoppix Live CD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be doable. Once you've booted up your system using the Knoppix LiveCD you'll need to open a shell and then determine what the device ID is for the SSD device. You can use a command such as `blkid` or `lsblk`, assuming they're available on Knoppix.

Once you've identified this, you can mount it:

```
$ mount /dev/sda1 /mnt
```

Once mounted you can manipulate the files as you'd normally do when booting with the SSD device. Be sure to unmount it when your done with it.

```
$ umount /dev/sda1
```

Comment: Should be mounted root or boot partition? Specifically, how to edit the `grub.cfg`?

Comment: What's the version of Debian? You'll wanting to be mounting the `/boot` partition. I generally open it in `nano` or `vim` and edit it, it's just a regular text file.

Comment: `linux-image-3.2.0-4-686-pae`, I mean steps after mount command, as I'm new to Linux.

Comment: What part of editing that file do you not understand? Once you mount it the `/boot` shows under `/mnt` and you navigate that directory structure to where the grub files are located and edit them. BTW my tone is nice in that sentence 8-)

Comment: There might be some confusion about the mounts.  Following up the `$ mount /dev/sda1 /mnt` with a `$ mount /dev/sda5 /mnt/boot` might be more clear since the question identified /boot as being on a separate partition, but update-grub needs / and /boot to read the config in /etc (unless the intention is to configure grub directly, bypassing debian scripting).